# Inserting bulk data into table by checking a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table with more than 1000 rows, which is having a column academic year with value 2014. Now I need to insert the same set of data with academic year as 2015. I can copy existing data to new table but, second time while copying I need to change academic year to 2015 by checking some condition. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like that :

```
insert into tableX (a,b,d,academic) 
select a,b,d, IF(a = 'll' and b='kk', 2015, 2014) from tableX;
```

Comment: **@Imanez** it is working when table is empty, and the condition needs to be checked only in the basis of academic year not on other fields. Once data is entered and again trying to execute same query it is not working.

Comment: sorry **@Imanez** I tried to insert primary key id also, that's why it wasn't working thanks